# NSFetchedResultsController CoreData UICollectionView insert Issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to update using a NSFetchedResultsController/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate a UICollectionView.
**UPDATE** The UICollectionView has 21 cells and it has 3 cell in each Row.

The idea is that I am downloading some image Data,I am saving them on CoreData on BackgroundContext 
`(backgroundContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.privateQueueConcurrencyType) 
backgroundContext.parent = context)
context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)`

While I am downloading and **saving on backgroundContext** the data, I am loading a new Controller with a UICollectionView and I am fetching the data that they are about to be saved on backgroundContext ,and the backgroundContext will inform the context for the new data, and with the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate functions I will update my UICollectionViewCells.

**UPDATE** The downloaded imageData from the API are 21 every time.

**Saving**

```
stack!.backgroundContext.perform({
                        let photoFrame = PhotoFrame(pin: pin, imageData: imageData as NSData, context: self.stack!.backgroundContext)
                        do{
                            try self.stack!.backgroundContext.save()
                            print("OK Saved Background")
                        }catch{
                            print("Error background saving")
                        }
                    })
```

Everything is ok I get Data Stored!

**NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate**

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        insertIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        deleteIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
        updateIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()

        print("*** controller will change content")
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        switch type{

        case .insert:
            print("Insert an item newIndexPath : \(newIndexPath!)")
            self.insertIndexPaths.append(newIndexPath!)

        case .delete:
            print("Delete an Item")
            deleteIndexPaths.append(indexPath!)

        case .update:
            print("Update an item")
            updateIndexPaths.append(indexPath!)

        case .move:
            print("move")


        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {


        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            for indexPath in self.insertIndexPaths {

                print("Inserting FetchedObjects at: \(indexPath)")
                self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])

            }

            for indexPath in self.deleteIndexPaths {
                self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
            }

            for indexPath in self.updateIndexPaths{
                self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            }

        }, completion: {finished in
            print("Finished")

        })
    }
```

and I am loading the cell with this function

**ConfigureCell**

```
cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        cell.collectionImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")


        if frc!.fetchedObjects!.count > 0 {
            if cell.collectionImageView.image == UIImage(named: "placeholder") {
                print("IndexPath: \(indexPath)")
                print("fetchedObjects : \(frc!.fetchedObjects!.count)")

                if let photoFrame = frc!.object(at: indexPath) as? PhotoFrame{

                    cell.collectionImageView.image = UIImage(data:(photoFrame.imageData! as NSData) as Data)
                    cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
```

Everything works ok BUT on the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate function

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)
```

I get this weird output when I run the app:

```
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 0]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 0]
IndexPath: [0, 0]
fetchedObjects : 1
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 0]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 0]
IndexPath: [0, 0]
fetchedObjects : 2
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 0]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 0]
IndexPath: [0, 0]
fetchedObjects : 3
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 1]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 1]
IndexPath: [0, 1]
fetchedObjects : 4
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 1]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 1]
IndexPath: [0, 1]
fetchedObjects : 5
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 2]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 2]
IndexPath: [0, 2]
fetchedObjects : 6
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 2]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 2]
IndexPath: [0, 2]
fetchedObjects : 7
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 3]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 3]
IndexPath: [0, 3]
fetchedObjects : 8
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 3]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 3]
IndexPath: [0, 3]
fetchedObjects : 9
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 4]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 4]
IndexPath: [0, 4]
fetchedObjects : 10
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 4]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 4]
IndexPath: [0, 4]
fetchedObjects : 11
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 5]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 5]
IndexPath: [0, 5]
fetchedObjects : 12
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 5]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 5]
IndexPath: [0, 5]
fetchedObjects : 13
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 6]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 6]
IndexPath: [0, 6]
fetchedObjects : 14
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 6]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 6]
IndexPath: [0, 6]
fetchedObjects : 15
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 7]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 7]
IndexPath: [0, 7]
fetchedObjects : 16
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 7]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 7]
IndexPath: [0, 7]
fetchedObjects : 17
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 8]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 8]
IndexPath: [0, 8]
fetchedObjects : 18
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 8]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 8]
IndexPath: [0, 8]
fetchedObjects : 19
OK Saved Background
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 9]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 9]
IndexPath: [0, 9]
fetchedObjects : 20
OK Saved Background
Success
*** controller will change content
Insert an item newIndexPath : [0, 9]
Inserting FetchedObjects at: [0, 9]
IndexPath: [0, 9]
fetchedObjects : 21
OK Saved Background
```

Any Idea why I am getting this duplicates indexPaths on the .insert(newIndexPath!) ?

Comment: What sort order have you specified for a) the fetch underlying the FRC, and b) the API request?  My guess is there is a subtle difference, so (for example), the FRC sorts the first three items in reverse order compared to the API.

Comment: Hi @pbasdf. Actually I had no SortDescriptor on that FRC and since I set a sortDescriptor I can see my results in order with no duplications But the same indexPaths are printed out. And actually it doesn't make any sense. Anyway you saved my day! Thanks a lot pbasdf